# What is a fast algorithm to get which positions are filled with 1 in a binary texture, on GLSL?

Tags: javascript, opengl-es, glsl, webgl

I have a binary 2d texture:

```
texture = [1,0,0,1,
           0,0,1,0,
           0,0,0,0,
           1,0,0,0];
```

I want to find out which pixels coordinates are filled with 1. In this case, for example, the result would be:

```
 [[0,0], [3,0], [2,1], [0,3]]
```

Because the coordinates `(0,0), (3,0), (2,1) and (0,3)` have an 1. I want to process that function inside a fragment shader using OpenGL-ES/GLSL. I've managed to find a `log(N)` solution. Is it possible to compute that result in a single pass of the shader?

Comment: What is this O (log N) solution you found? I can think of one off the top of my head right now using `textureGather (...)`, but that is a GL4 feature and will not work in ES. You might still be able to take advantage of the fact that linear texture filtering takes 4 samples at a time and performs a weighted average to reduce the number of required fetches even if you do not have access to `textureGather (...)`.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman hmm...? I'm considering a pass to be 1 (because it happens in parallel), so `log(N)` passes (using a foldl) or `log(N)*N` operations if you prefer.

Comment: The fastest implementation I've seen is with histogram pyramids: http://domino.mpi-inf.mpg.de/internet/reports.nsf/c125634c000710d4c12560410043ec01/7197d211ab5f25a9c1257323002e2595/$FILE/MPI-I-2007-4-006.pdf , where you're looking at log(N) performance. Ignoring the order of the operation, the fact that this stays entirely on the GPU should make it reasonably fast, but I don't think you're going to find a solution that operates in a single pass, short of a very slow iteration over every pixel.